# New entries not appearing on template page

Tags: templating, entries, channels

My client has been adding some new entries in a channel called Products. These are using different templates that are selected when creating the entry.

The entries on a few different template types are no longer appearing in the last few days. I have checked that the templates have all the correct field handles and there doesn't seem to be anything missing. I have also tried clearing the cache.

Does anyone have any idea why new entries may not be appearing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are there more than 100 entries in the products channel? If so, you'll need to specify the limit. All Craft requests are limited to 100 by default.

`{% for entry in craft.entries.products.limit(null) %}`

If not, please post your template code :)

Comment: That was what I was after, solved the issue perfectly - thanks for the help.